# ActiveCollab 5 API: 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: c#, api, activecollab

I've been using the API for over a year now. And since yesterday I've haven't been able to make one successful GET call. Since the application was moved to production I've gotten a few 500 Internal Server Errors but not for over 24 hours straight. Its a console application that runs every 15 minutes to pull projects, tasks and time for payroll.

API Documention: https://developers.activecollab.com/api-documentation/index.html

SDK GitHub: https://github.com/activecollab/activecollab-feather-sdk

Example of HttpRequestMessage I'm sending

```
Method: GET, 
RequestUri: 'https://app.activecollab.com/[app-id]/api/v1/companies/all', 
Version: 1.1, 
Content: <null>, 
Headers: {
  X-Angie-AuthApiToken: [api-token]
}
```

Every GET call I make is returning a 500 Internal Server Error.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Finally figured out the issue, it was a bad api token. Once I issued a new token everything started working.

Not sure why the token all of sudden stopped working.